# Read only access to issues in github

Tags: github

I have a private repository on Github where I have defined two teams, one with write access to the repository and the other one with read access.

However people with read access are still able to create issues on the repo.

Is there any way to accomplish this setup, that is, read only access to issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like the answer is "No".  But Github suggests you create a second repository for issues only.

See below:

https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-issues-only-repository/

Answer (score 0):

You can make issues read-only by adding `.github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE/config.yml` to the repository and inside set `blank_issues_enabled` to `false` and not adding any templates.

An example config from [github documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/communities/using-templates-to-encourage-useful-issues-and-pull-requests/configuring-issue-templates-for-your-repository#configuring-the-template-chooser) renders only the two links included in the config and no way to create an issue:

```yaml
blank_issues_enabled: false
contact_links:
  - name: GitHub Community Support
    url: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions
    about: Please ask and answer questions here.
  - name: GitHub Security Bug Bounty
    url: https://bounty.github.com/
    about: Please report security vulnerabilities here.
```

However, this makes the issues read-only for everyone.